# (python) unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, pandas, function, integer

basically I want to run a function in a DataFrame like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({"col1" : [10,20,30,40,50,60],
    "col" : [
        [(0.14507, 0.163054, 0.330704), (0.069578, 0.075506, 0.145531), (0.039168, 0.042362, 0.097616), (0.038133, 0.04009, 0.079482), (0.039872, 0.041051, 0.06478), (0.039158, 0.039898, 0.054787), (0.03744, 0.037917, 0.047526), (0.035354, 0.035669, 0.041999), (0.033199, 0.03341, 0.037646), (0.031113, 0.031256, 0.034127), (0.02916, 0.029257, 0.031222), (0.027361, 0.027428, 0.028784), (0.02572, 0.025767, 0.026709)],
        np.nan,
        [(0.000341, 0.000391, 0.000991), (0.006122, 0.006682, 0.013834), (0.008017, 0.008671, 0.01998), (0.011591, 0.012186, 0.02416), (0.016047, 0.016522, 0.026072), (0.019587, 0.019957, 0.027405), (0.022358, 0.022643, 0.028382), (0.024514, 0.024733, 0.029122), (0.02619, 0.026356, 0.029698), (0.027492, 0.027618, 0.030155), (0.028507, 0.028602, 0.030523), (0.0293, 0.029373, 0.030825), (0.029924, 0.029979, 0.031075)],
        [(0.003174, 0.003642, 0.009186), (0.007794, 0.008506, 0.017575), (0.009007, 0.009741, 0.022447), (0.012455, 0.013094, 0.025961), (0.016847, 0.017345, 0.027372), (0.020272, 0.020655, 0.028363), (0.022917, 0.023209, 0.029091), (0.024952, 0.025175, 0.029642), (0.026517, 0.026685, 0.03007), (0.027721, 0.027848, 0.030406), (0.028649, 0.028745, 0.030676), (0.029367, 0.02944, 0.030895), (0.029924, 0.029979, 0.031075)],
        [(0.013956, 0.01599, 0.039581), (0.013662, 0.014903, 0.030583), (0.012198, 0.013193, 0.0304), (0.01502, 0.015791, 0.031306), (0.018966, 0.019527, 0.030814), (0.021805, 0.022217, 0.030508), (0.023863, 0.024167, 0.030291), (0.025358, 0.025584, 0.030124), (0.026444, 0.026612, 0.029987), (0.027231, 0.027356, 0.029868), (0.027797, 0.02789, 0.029763), (0.028202, 0.028271, 0.029669), (0.028488, 0.02854, 0.029584)],
        [(0.016686, 0.019111, 0.047087), (0.014983, 0.016342, 0.033484), (0.012816, 0.013861, 0.031941), (0.01542, 0.016211, 0.03214), (0.019175, 0.019742, 0.031154), (0.021806, 0.022218, 0.030509), (0.023671, 0.023972, 0.030047), (0.024995, 0.025218, 0.029694), (0.025935, 0.026099, 0.029409), (0.026596, 0.026718, 0.029172), (0.027056, 0.027147, 0.02897), (0.027371, 0.027438, 0.028795), (0.02758, 0.02763, 0.02864)],
    ]
})
```

I did some transformation in the second column and I named other variable for my function.

```
data["col"] = data['col'].apply(lambda x: np.array(x))
data["col"] = data["col"].fillna('0')
cer = float(0.011346536786715513)
```

But when I run this function:

```
def pom(a):
    ts = [np.array(1.0),]
    pomarg = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        TS = ts[i] * (1 - a[i] - cer)
        PDm = ts[i] * a[i]
        
        ts.append(TS)
        pomarg.append(PDm)
    
    return pomarg


data['pom'] = data['col'].apply(lambda x: pom(x))
```

I have the following mistake:

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Do you know how come I'm getting this error?
Thanks!

Comment: could you show us how are you running the function `pom` in the dataframe?

Comment: Tried `pdm(np.arange(10))`. No error. Question's title also doesn't match with error in the question's body.

Comment: Sorry. Send you the line of the execution of the function: ```data['pom'] = data['col'].apply(lambda x: pom(x))
```

Comment: `fillna('0')` should be `fillna(0)`

Comment: Why does the error in your title have nothing to do with the error in your question?

Comment: As @Barmar suggests, I also add that `fillna('0')` should be `fillna(0)`. And in the `pom` function I included a `try except` in case `a` is 0. In that case, I assign `a` to `[0]` (force it to be a list). Not sure if this should be the case but is a workaround.

Comment: I tried with ```fillna(0)``` but when use this line is when ```unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'``` appears

Comment: Also, there is an extra issue, because in the real dataframe the variables are string.